R tidysynth synthetic control not generating correct weights
I am trying to produce a synthetic control for my data where the control weights are simply based on the donor units' goodness-of-fit to the outcome variable during the pre-treatment period (minimizing RMSPE). There are no covariates.
Unfortunately, the code I'm using does not produce the right weights. Instead, the weights for all the donor units are roughly equivalent (all 44 weights are between 2.2% and 2.7%). I know these are not the correct weights. I believe just a few of the donor units should have most of the weight because their outcomes are more similar to the treated unit in pre-period. What am I missing or doing wrong?
Example data:



unit_id
week_id
sales




1
1
4654


1
2
5643


1
3
4898


...
...
...


45
49
3434


45
50
3248



Code:
output <- df_6 %>%
  # Initial synthetic control object
  synthetic_control(outcome = sales, # the 4-week moving average sales
                    unit = unit_id, # numeric identifier for unit name
                    time = week_id, # numeric variable for time period
                    i_unit = "45", # unit_id for the treated unit
                    i_time = "25", # week_id for intervention period
                    generate_placebos= TRUE
                    ) %>%
  # Generate the aggregate predictors used to generate the weights
  generate_predictor( time_window = 1:24,
                      sales = mean(sales, na.rm = TRUE)
                      ) %>%
  # Generate the fitted weights for the synthetic control
  generate_weights(optimization_window = 1:24,
                  ) %>%
  # Generate the synthetic control
  generate_control() 


weights <- grab_unit_weights(output)

